# What is benefit of SingleThreadPool over synchronization?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, thread-synchronization

I was studing about ExecutorService.
I found that there are 4 types of Thread pools. 
1. FixedThreadPool

```
int coreCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();  
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(coreCount);
```

2. CachedThreadPool

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

here threads are automatically created if no created thread is free and deleted when a thread is idle by JVM.
Threads are stored in queue.

3. ScheduledThreadPool
   Threads are stored in a delay queue
   this queue can sort the element based on their scheduled occurrence.

Service.schedule
Service.scheduleAtFixedRate
Service.scheduleAtFixedDelay

Schedule the tasks to run based on time delay (and retrigger for fixedRate / fixedDelay)
Life Cycle: More threads are created if required.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool ( 10);
// task to run after 10 second delay
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Task(),  10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// task to run repeatedly every 10 seconds
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(),  15,  10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// task to run repeatedly 10 seconds after previous task completes
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task(),  15,  10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

4. SingleThreadedExecutor
   when you require to run thread in a sequential order you should use SingleThreadPoolService.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

**So my question is the single Thread Executor looks very similar to Synchronized operations. Can anyone please describe any difference between those two. any benefit over synchronization. What was the motivation for a Single Thread executor ? means why thread at all ?**

Comment: Poor `ForkJoinPool` was left to the wind I suppose. A single-threaded `ExecutorService` is very different from `synchronized` and its usages, what do you mean by "Synchronized operations"? Note that the single thread in that `ExecutorService` is _not_ the current thread, so you're submitting tasks for that other thread to consume. You'd want this if the tasks you're submitting might take a long time / block the current thread, or if that service is responsible for some single area (e.g. a gui rendering thread)

Comment: Thread pool and synchronization are not related. A single thread executor just ensures a sequential order of some tasks, it does not stop another thread accessing the same set of underlying objects in use by those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement analog of single thread executor with a Thread and some synchronized code, however it would take lots of effort. For example, some things you have to implement manually:

1. A queue of tasks. Task submission (not execution) to an executor would be performed immediately, task would be stored for later execution. Every call to synchronized block would wait, so you have to store task manually in order to archive similar behaviour.
2. Order of task execution.
3. Task submission to an executor returns a Future

So look at a executors API and think how could you implement it manually and you see a lot of work to do.

Answer (score -1):

SingleThreadExecutor makes sure all requests gets executed by a single thread. Imagine a physical kiosk taking orders from customers in queue.

Comment: yes! My question was why can not we do it in main thread or single Runnable or Callable ? Why we need ExecutorService ? Can we not do it in a synchroized way.

Comment: @OP That would be a good thing to include in the original question.